# Should I call Source.Seek(0,soFromBeginning) after TFileStream.Create?

Tags: delphi, stream

I have seen in quite few places (one example here: http://pascalgamedevelopment.com/archive/index.php/t-1204.html) people doing this.

Embarcadero documentation says nothing about the position of the header in the file/stream after creating the stream.

---

**Conclusion:**

Since the documentation does not guaranty the position of the cursor, we should use 'Seek=0'. Even if now the cursor is placed at the beginning of the file, we will never know how this will change in time. Since Embarcadero does not document this, it looks like they reserve the right to change it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

TFileStream.Create just opens file handle and leaves file position where the Win32 put it after the handle was open - at the beginning on the file.

There's no need to Seek to 0 position; you are already there.

Comment: +1 but I would still recommend calling "Position := 0;" if you're opening the stream in read or read/write mode just to be on the safe side.

Comment: @Dorin. I don't understand why. Please explain.

Comment: We can't really know what will change in the future(in the RTL source), so, in this way you can rest assured that after you create a handle to the file you set the position of the cursor at the beginning of the stream. It's the way I do it...

Comment: I disagree, @Dorin. We can really know that it will never change and we can absolutelly rest assured that after creation of the handle the file will always have it positioned at 0.

Comment: He might be right - Embarcadero does not document this (what happens with the position of the header after opening the file). This could to mean 'we don't guaranty it'.

Comment: @PA if for whatever reason, in XE 3, 4, etc. EMB has a bug slipped(i.e. some memory overwrite) and the cursor is positioned randomly when you open in read or read/write mode, and you expect it to be at zero and your code does not at least check if position is zero, then depending on the scale of your code and other, you can waste hours of debugging easily. At the end of the day it really depends on your choice, add the extra line of code or not. As Altar already mentioned, EMB has really bad documentation, compare it to Delphi 7's and you will be amazed...

Comment: P.S. better to be safe than sorry.

Comment: @Dorin - I agree with you on 'better safe than sorry' but in this case will be hundreds of places where we should add extra code 'just in case' some bug slips in in future versions of Delphi. But in this very specific case, because it isn't actually specified in the documentation, I agree that Seek should be mandatory used!

Comment: @Altar it's entirely up to the developer to do what he thinks is the best.